# JWT logout feature without using blacklist?

Tags: jwt, logout

I have used `JWT` before, but they were `API` that didn't need logout feature.

I need to implement logout feature for a `API` of an android app and `SPA`. When I looked it up I found that there are two ways to do it.

1. the easiest way is to delete the `JWT Token` from client side and call it a day.

The logic behind this is that since no session of any kind is maintained in server deleting the token in client side should be enough.
But it still leaves the possibility that, if the token falls in wrong hands they can still use it even after the user is no longer using the token.

Given if the app is well designed and uses `HTTPS` then chances of this happening is very low and can be minimized by keeping the valid time for the token short. But in my case the tokens are valid for 30 days.

2. the second option is to maintain a blacklist of tokens in server side

This solves the problem of the token still being usable even after user has logged out and stopped using it.

But it adds a complication of needing to run a `cronjob` to remove expired token form the blacklist table. Otherwise the table will eventually become ridiculously large.

It also kinda defeats the point of using `JWT`. Maintaining blacklist is very similar to maintaining session. We have to run an additional db query for every request. And it scales badly, as the no. of users grows the no. of token that needs to be blacklisted will also grow (this will be a bigger problem for `API` like mine with multiple front end apps and long validity period for the tokens).

Then I got an idea for third way.

Add `jwt_secret` row in user table that stores randomly generated string. Use it to sign the `JWT Token` then on every request use `user id` in the `jwt payload` to get the user form db(which is not an extra query, we have to do this anyway) and validate the token signature using `jwt_secret` of the user. When the user logs out we change the `jwt_secret` which makes all token out there useless.

At first I thought this  was a great solution only to realize that in this setup if user logs out of one device or browser he/she gets logged out of all devices.

So is there a another option? Or a way to modify any of above approach to solve the problem. Or am I over thinking this and one of the above option should be used?

Comment: You could use the `aud` and `jti` claims in the JWT to issue separate JWT token to each device, then based on the `aud` id you could invalidate only one client's session. This requires you to uniquely identify a client, or always issue new `aud`, which will clutter your db and slow down claim validation, or have a periodic cleanup of long-unused session table...

If you combine this with the per-user secret, you have to choice of invalidating one client or all of them (log out vs. log out on all devices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For logging out, which as you pointed out is a user initiated action, I don't think you need to do anything extra.  If the user somehow did not delete his JWT, then so be it.  He wouldn't be getting any extra access over to what he is already entitled.

However, your question seems to hint on the problem of how to know that a JWT is valid.  Again, as you pointed out, if a JWT somehow fell into the wrong hands, then there may be no avoiding this.  But, with each request you would typically be doing several types of validation against that JWT, e.g.

- checking the claims of the JWT, such as the token expiry date
- assuming the claims pass, then checking that user's ID against your database table to make sure the account is active, has not been suspended, etc.

My point here is that if you need to keep track on the server side that a logout has happened, you might need to persist this to a database.  But, I don't think you would need this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have come to the same conclusion as well and just wanted a second opinion.

Comment: You should use a per-user (stored) secret, which you can delete, invalidating all JWT tokens based on the old secret.